# Identifying a mushroom. (Pyrenees near Gavarnie, France)

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Can anyone help me identify this mushroom? (a still frame from video taken in the Pyrenees near Gavarnie in France). Also is it edible or poisonous?

[image: Pyrenees Mushroom]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly the parasol mushroom, *Macrolepiota procera*. The parasol mushroom is edible, but many other often resembling mushrooms are not. **Never eat a wild mushroom unless you're an expert or consulted one**.
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macrolepiota_procera
[image]

Comment: Very helpful. Thank-you very much....and also for the note of caution. :0)

Comment: @OrbitRob If you think your question has been answered, please check the checkmark next to the answer.